# What do the DirectMapXX fields signify in meminfo?

Tags: linux, memory

What do DirectMap4K/DirectMap2M signify in the ouput of /proc/meminfo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They give the amount of memory mapped in that page size by the x86 [TLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_lookaside_buffer).

Comment: What is memory mapped in that page size by the TLB? Are those the internal kernel structures needed for multi level TLB? Why do i see nonzero DirectMap1G even though i do not have 1gb pages even enabled at boot time?